# Drawing a Line On A White Image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, plot

I'm attempting to draw a graph on a blank image, using the cvLine method to go from point to point. Holder[] is an array of floaters. I have checked the array by printing out values, so it is not empty.

```
IplImage* blank = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3); 
cvSet(blank, CV_RGB(255,255,255));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < height; i++) 
 {
cvLine(blank, cvPoint (i, holder[i]/100),  cvPoint (i+1, holder[i+1]/100), cvScalar(0,255,0),  8, 1);
 }

cvNamedWindow("Graph Title", 1);
cvShowImage("Graph Title", blank);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

When I run this code all I get is a white image, no plot.

Comment: First of all you are trying to draw colored lines(green) on a gray image(you've put 1 channel). Second, make sure that you're points are inside the image space and not outside.

Comment: Thank you, I've made some changes: IplImage* blank = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, max + 50),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);     and I changed the height of the picture to fix the max value in holder[];. However, I have no picture yet.

Comment: Also correct your for (i = 0; i < height; i++) , and you're using the variable 'i' as the x coordinate but you say it goes up to the height ?!

Comment: Height here is not the height of the image I'm trying to draw. It's the height of another picture from which I obtain intensity values along pixel rows and the put them into holder[]. So holder[] has height number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by declaring i and holder[i] inside the for loop, before the cvLine method.

```
for (i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{
int x1 = i;
int y1 = holder[i]/100;
int x2 = i + 1;
int y2 = holder[i+1]; 
cvLine(blank, cvPoint (x1, y1),  cvPoint (x2, y2), cvScalar(0,255,0),  8, 1);
}
```